# Java Hangman - replacing underscore with character

Tags: java, arrays, char, stringbuilder

So I'm creating a hangman game for my java class, but I'm having troubles replacing the underscores in the word with letters. I got it to print out the word in underscores like:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < GuessWord.length(); i++) { 
                if (guesses[GuessWord.charAt(i) - 'a']) { 
                    mainword.append(words[i].charAt(i));
                }
                else {
                    mainword.append("_");

                }
                mainword.append(" ");
            }
```

The rest is the rest of my code. I should mention I'm working in Netbeans IDE 7.2 and I'm using a JLayeredPane to display everything, not System.out.print. Thanks!

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public MainFrame() {
            initComponents();
        }

    //declare variables                      
    static String SecretWord = "";
    static String Letters = "";
    double Result = 0;
    String SetMain = null;
    StringBuilder mainword = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder gletters = new StringBuilder();
    boolean[] guesses = new boolean[26];
    String[] words = {"technology", "computer", "camera", "graphic design", "digital", "media", "technician", "photography", "troubleshoot", "pixels", "application", "download"};
    Random r = new Random();
    int randvalue = r.nextInt(11);
    String GuessWord = words[randvalue];


        private void GoButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    mainword.append(SecretWord);
    //make word in underscore form
        for(int i = 0; i < GuessWord.length(); i++) { 
                if (guesses[GuessWord.charAt(i) - 'a']) { 
                    mainword.append(words[i].charAt(i));
                }
                else {
                    mainword.append("_");

                }
                mainword.append(" ");
            }

   //put in label
   SetMain = mainword.toString();
   WordLabel.setText(SetMain);
   GuessButton.setEnabled(true);
   GoButton.setEnabled(false);
}                           


private void GuessButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    //declare variables      
    String strGuess = GuessText.getText();
    String SetMain = null;
    String GuessedLetters = null;
    Result = 1;//(int)(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
    int errors = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char guess2 = strGuess.charAt(i);
    gletters.append(Letters);

    //*******MAJOR PROBLEM AREA FOCUS HERE*******
    do{
        //replace underscore with guessed letter
        for(i = 0; i < GuessWord.length(); i++) { 
                if (GuessWord.charAt(i) == guess2) { 
                   mainword.replace(0,i,strGuess.toUpperCase()); 
                }
                else {
                    mainword.append("_");

                }
                mainword.append(" ");
            }

    //put in labels
    SetMain = mainword.toString();
    GuessedLetters = gletters.toString();
    WordLabel.setText(SetMain);
    GuessedLabel.setText(GuessedLetters);
    GuessText.setText(null);
    GuessText.requestFocusInWindow();
    }//end of do

while(SetMain == null);
if (SetMain.equalsIgnoreCase(GuessWord)){
    //show winning message to user and reset game
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrats!");
    GuessButton.setEnabled(false);
    GoButton.setEnabled(true);
    WordLabel.setText(null);
    GuessedLabel.setText(null);
    WinsLabel.setText("1");
}
//if too many errors show lost message
else if (errors >= 5){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lost!");
    GuessButton.setEnabled(false);
    GoButton.setEnabled(true);
    WordLabel.setText(null);
    GuessedLabel.setText(null);
    LossesLabel.setText("1");
}
    }//end of 1GAME
}
```

Any help would be great! Please nothing too complicated. Also I marked where my major problem area is in the above code.

Comment: Show us the whole stack trace of the error.

Comment: updated. but that's not the main focus

Comment: *"that's not the main focus"* ?!?  Do you want to *solve* the error?

Comment: GuessWord.length() what is the return value?

Comment: By what logic is it not? The exception is telling you that you're running out of memory somewhere in there. You should improve your code as it is not clear, indented and properly structured, as it should be if you'd have followed a tutorial on oracle.com. And your comments are futile, perhaps even to you.

Comment: BTW - `"graphic design"`  Putting multi-word expressions in a Hangman game seems like cheating.  ;)

Comment: The big problem I'm having is replacing the underscores with the letters. The error I figured out is a problem with my memory, I have too much stuff on my computer. I don't get that error anymore

Comment: *"I don't get that error anymore"*  <rhetorical>Why do I have the feeling we'll end up going round in circles?</rhetorical>  If that is no longer the error, is the code shown still the code that caused it?

Comment: Seriously, you need to learn to ask questions.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, That's how I'm feeling. I just had large pictures in my project, I deleted them and the error is gone. I run the program, everything works except when I click the "guess" button, nothing happens. What I want is the letter to be revealed in the hidden word. Am I confusing anyone yet?

Comment: I think one of your problems is that `GuessWord.indexOf(i)` is probably not what you're looking for - read up on the [documentation of the String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) - I'm guessing you really wanted `charAt()`.  And what is it with professors not teaching the coding standards, or even basic design practices?

Comment: @iccthedral, I'm new here and I have the code indented on my Netbeans, but it didn't transfer over well. My bad:)

Comment: I put in the charAt like you said, and it now says:
if (GuessWord.charAt(i) == guess2) { mainword.replace(0,i,strGuess.toUpperCase()); 
is the problem the guess2 variable?

Comment: I would just like to say please go easy on me, I know the java basics but I have only been doing this for about 3 months. And I have looked at MANY java hangman games but they all were either too complicated or used System.out.print (which I can't use)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach. We do not try to replace not-guessed letters with a placeholder. Here we remember all letters, that have been guessed so far (in a set) and recreate the "view" of the secret word for each turn. The demo code includes a stupid player that just randomly guesses all letters of the alphabet.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    String secretWord = "fibonacci";
    Set<Character> guessedLetters = new HashSet<>();

    // (1) create some test input (all letters randomized)
    List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        chars.add(c);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(chars);

    // (2) Let's guess
    for (char guessedLetter : chars) {
        // (3) memorize all letters that have been guessed
        guessedLetters.add(guessedLetter);

        // (4) print the display version of the secret word
        boolean guessedCompletely = true;
        System.out.print("My guess: [" + guessedLetter + "] -> ");
        for (char letterOfSecretWord : secretWord.toCharArray()) {
            if (guessedLetters.contains(letterOfSecretWord)) {
                // (4a) - we already guessed this letter
                System.out.print(letterOfSecretWord);
            } else {
                // (4b) - we haven't guessed it so far
                guessedCompletely = false;
                System.out.print('_');
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        // (5) check, if the game is won
        if (guessedCompletely) {
            System.out.println("Yeah!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's java 7. If you can't compile with javac 7, simply replace the `<>` with `<Character>`

Comment: okay, so the guessedletters variable holds all of the guessedletters, and if one of those letters is in the secret word, then what? does it replace? for instance the word hello: "_ _ _ _ _ " would change to " _ e _ _ _" if the letter e was guessed

Comment: Compile it, run it and see. There's no need in "replacing" chars by placeholders. The trick is to re-create the "visible" part of the secret word for each round (replacing would create new strings too, btw)

Comment: okay so i see how it worked, but how would u change it from being completely random to actually getting a persons guess?

Comment: Replace the outer for loop with something that captures input from a user. Like a do-while loop with some code to get user input. Or take the "idea" and implement it in your own code :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a simpler approach, in which you hold an array of characters that you can change based on an input. This is an overal description of the idea:

```
char guess[] = {'_', '_', '_', '_', '_', ' ', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'};
// It's "Hello World" :)
if(input == answer.getCharAt(inputIndex))
    guess[inputIndex] = answer.getCharAt(inputIndex); 
    //replace the underscore with the correct character
else
    //Add it to a list of used characters, ignore it or do as you've been asked to
```

In your case, create this `guess` array by invoking `answer.toCharArray()` where `answer` is the string that has the correct word. You'll want to replace all the characters in that string with underscores by using `replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9]", "_")` (just remember to keep the original answer too). The first parameter is a regular expression that means "The group of All characters from A to Z, from a to z and from 0 to 9", you'll want to check up some [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to get used to them, and trust me, you'll use them more sooner than later.

Then, you'll just want to replace `guess[i]` with `answer.getCharAt(i)` everytime a guess is done correctly, avoiding the tedious work of building a string character by character which can be tricky.

This is a brief description of a different approach, since it's an assigment you can decide if you want to try it or not and the general implementation is up to you. I'll just describe an idea.

Comment: would i have to make char guess[] for every word of mine?

Comment: `inputIndex` is just a variable that determines the index of the guess. When you make a guess, each character you try is associated to a particular position in the guessword. For example, if you try `A` in the 3rd space, `inputIndex` is 2 (the array starts at 0). Regarding the `guess` array, you can have one and assign it the current word like `guess = createGuessArray(word)` where `createGuessArray` is a method that replaces the characters for underscores and returns that "masked" guessword turning it into a char array with `toCharArray()`.